# error C1083: cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 returns this error when I tried to build a Snare (http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/BackLogNT/) project.

I installed the `Windows SDK` and I realized that I am supposed to include the SDK path into my project. Could anyone explain how to include the SDK path into a Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013, under Solution Explorer, right click on the project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories, then include (WindowsSDK_IncludePath_um); in Include and Library Directories. I was able to solve this issue with this approach.

Comment: I tried installing the windows 7 and windows 8 SDKs, but this was the answer that resolved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by user2644318 is quite hardcoded. An alternative is to try this:
- Open the Project properties
- Goto Configuration Properties -> General
- Set the Platform Toolset to v120_xp (Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP)
- Recompile

Funnily enough I can mix toolsets for libraries; they link fine. Ofcourse, this only gets you XP interface capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

I think answer of Ruud van Gaal is more correct.
What I did:
- install Windows SDK for Windows XP (7.1) from here
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

- open the Project properties - Goto Configuration Properties -> General - Set the Platform Toolset to "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)"
- after this Include/Libraries paths were changed to correct folders 
  $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSdk_71A_IncludePath);
  $(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSdk_71A_LibraryPath_x86);

So I did NOT change them manually.
Only targeting correct tool set and everything started to work.

Comment: This looks like more of a comment on another answer.  Pleas post it as such when you can.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded and installed windows SDK 8.1 for my windows 7. VS2013 looks for winsock2.h header in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1 folder. This approach works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering the same problem in Visual Studio 2019, the problem might be that you started off with a completely blank project. It literally states that there are *no* *starting* *files*. So instead I created a new project based on any other than "*Empty Project*". Now I could find winsock-files in external dependencies.

It may sound like a lazy workaround, but it will save you from the startup headache of having to tamper with include paths.